# Convert a timestamp to local time

Tags: time-date, parse-time

I have a timestamp string `"2011-01-23T16:18:46-08:00"` and I want to convert it to my local time zone.

```
(format-time-string  
    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" 
    (decode-time (parse-iso8601-time-string "2011-01-23T16:18:46-08:00")))
```

gives

```
"1970-02-04T13:24:34-0800"
```

which is off by several decades. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parse-iso8601-time-string` already returns a time value that `format-time-string` accepts:

```
(format-time-string
 "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
 (parse-iso8601-time-string "2011-01-23T16:18:46-08:00"))
     => "2011-01-24T08:18:46+0800"
```